# getting response 401 in power bi GET request

Tags: powerbi

```
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets
```

by sending GET request to above url, i am getting 401 error.

Added Content-Type:application/json,
Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

how to solve this issue?

Am i missing any settings in the power bi report server, I see Api Access as "--" is it the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You are taking about "power bi report server", but the get datasets URI (https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets) is the REST API for Power BI Service. If you want to send request to a Power BI Report Server on premise, the request should be sent to your on premise host.

Otherwise, check your application rights - does it has rights to read (Read All Datasets) or write (Read and Write All Datasets) datasets? You can decode your access token at https://jwt.io and check does scp contain "Dataset.Read.All" or "Dataset.ReadWrite.All".

UPDATE: Try to get more detailed information about the error by reading the content of the response. To do it, use code like this:

```
private void GetDatasets(string accessToken)
{
    string powerBIDatasetsApiUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets";

    var request = WebRequest.Create(powerBIDatasetsApiUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentLength = 0;
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
    try
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show(responseContent, "Get Datasets");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        if (ex.Response != null)
        {
            using (var errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(errorResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var errorString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    MessageBox.Show(errorString);
                }
            }
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

}

Comment: I am using power bi free trial, Is it the reason i am getting 403 error? @Andrey Nikolov

Comment: No, it isn't a problem. Check the contents of your response, not only the status code. What is the message that you get?

Comment: content-length:
0
server:
Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
strict-transport-security:
max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
x-frame-options:
deny
x-content-type-options:
nosniff
requestid:
7c58d341-1d05-43e4-9d9f-782790ecdcd8
date:
Thu, 08 Nov 2018 16:12:30 GMT @Andrey Nikolov

Comment: This isn't the response content, but the headers. I will update my answer to give you C# code how to do this.